# Foreman/Puppet: Add User to sudoers with a module

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, foreman, puppet-foreman

I would like to improve my skills in `Foreman` and `Puppet`. To do so I would like to get some easy tasks done.

In my configuration all servers belonging to host group "Basic" should get a basic setup - including adding a new user and adding this to the sudsers-file.

To do so I'm using [example42/sudo](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/example42/sudo)

Now I would like to add a user by adding a file to the directory `/etc/sudoers.d/`.

The documentation tells me to use `sudo::directive`.

This is an example:

```
sudo::directive { 'jenkins':
  content => "jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/puppi \n", # Double quotes and newline (\n) are needed here
}
```

Now my question is: I know how to add a class to a host group. I also know how to override params.

My current configuration for the host group "Basis" looks like this:

[image: Foreman config]

But how can I use `sudo::directive` in Foreman?

Comment: If you make screen shots, please set the language to english for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

External Node Classifiers such as Foreman are not meant to allow you to declare individual resources directly. You can do a couple of things:

- define global variable values
- declare classes
- define class parameter values

Since the module you are using does not offer a class parameter that takes a [hash value](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#createresources) to describe some initial resources, you cannot do this with the ENC directly.

You could build a custom module that takes a hash value and declares `sudo::directive` resources for you using `create_resources`.

Comment: http://projects.theforeman.org/projects/foreman/wiki/Instantiate_Puppet_resources has some examples of create_resources etc.